# How to add the more than two paasing values in "sAjaxSource" in jquery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to passing the two direct value in jquery sAjaxSource, I try this type but does not work. when pass the single its suceess

success:

```
"sAjaxSource": "/controller/action?" + "Id=" + $('#Ddl1').val(),
```

unsuccess:

> "sAjaxSource": "/controller/action?" + "Id=" + $('#Ddl1').val(), +
>   "nameId=" + $('#Ddl2').val(),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a query string. You're probably just missing the `&` in front of `nameId` and adding an unnecessary comma, try changing it to this:

```
"sAjaxSource": "/controller/action?" + "Id=" + $('#Ddl1').val() + "&nameId=" + $('#Ddl2').val(),
```